# In active-model-serializers, how to limit the associated objects returned from a has_many association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, active-model-serializers

So I have

```
    render json: Post.all
```

This returns all my Posts and in my Post serializer I have

```
    class PostSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
      has_many :comments
    end
```

I want the number of comments returned in the JSON to be limited to 5 and have a variable which tells if more comments are there. Is this possible?

Edit: I think I'll manage the more part with a new call. But can't figure out how to limit the comments in the serializer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your comments model write a scope method to limit the number of comments.

In **models/comment.rb**

```
scope :limited_comments, lambda { limit(5) }
```

In `PostSerializer`

```
has_many :comments

def comments
  Comment.limited_comments
end
```

Comment: Just doing Comment.limited_comments returned comments limited to 5 but removed the scope of Post id so I got comments from different posts.  
Writing a where statement ahead of that was an fix though. Thank you! Any idea how I can give a has_more boolean along with the data?

Comment: Define a has_more method in the serializer and include in the attributes

Comment: This will trigger N+1s if you're trying to access several `Post`s

Answer (score 11):

```
has_many :comments do
  @object.comments.limit(5)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I afraid that there isn't any way to limit amount of returned records in the serializer. However you can limit your records in controller with below lines.

```
# This code returns last 5 posts    
posts = Post.last(5)

render json: posts
```

Did you think about implementing some kind of pagination feature here?

Comment: But that would limit the Posts sent. I want to limit the number of comments which come back with the post. I will add pagination to Posts later. Wanted to see this out first